# How can I use Coalesce with Group_Concat to not return anything vs Empty '' or NULL?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I need to use coalesce other wise I get NULL output if any of the gathered records doesn't have a value in it. Yet when I use Coalesce with (Value, NULL) I end up with results like

```
A|B|NULL|D
```

likewise (Value, '')

```
A|B|''|D
```

when I am looking for

```
A|B|D
```

So how can I tell Mysql 'If some records don't have values till populate the ones that do, and only those ones, with the separator of my choice'?

Comment: `group_concat` [ignores null](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54dc1465c0269f37a0c9ae7baaf8ff8c) values. Can you please provide a simple query and data that illustrates the problem? BTW, `COALESCE(value, NULL)` makes no sense: it says to evaluate as `NULL` when `value IS NULL`, but that you already have without `COALESCE`

Comment: I will work on the example for sure it is a complex query / data so will need to simplify. Meanwhile yes Group_Contact ignores but that means I end up with a NULL result if any of the aggregated values is NULL. So I don't get A|B|D I get NULL which is even worse than A|B|NULL|D or A|B|''|D. Thus my hope is to use COALESCE to not get a NULL output but also to ignore in the Group_Concat values that are NULL.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen. I probably misunderstand what you are talking about. Please prove your point with an example.

Comment: FWIW since I like to come up with interim solutions when I hit a snag, since the select was returning unwanted empty values in my Group_Concat string e.g. `A, B, '', D, '', F`, for now I just wrapped it in a `Replace` so `Replace(Group_Contact, ', ','')`.

Comment: *the select was returning unwanted empty values in my Group_Concat string e.g. `A, B, '', D, '', F`* If so then your problem is backward. You have not NULLs but zero-length strings. NULLIF() will solve.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd4c55435dd767ad598318b8c7186ca4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data are but, why don't you try [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) with [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) like:

```
select id,group_concat(my_column separator '|')
from (select id, concat_ws('|',col1,col2,col3,col4) as my_column
      from test_tbl 
      ) as t1
group by id ;
```

Data examples:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl(
id int,
col1 varchar(30) ,
col2 varchar(30),
col3 varchar(30),
col4 varchar(30));

insert into test_tbl values
(1,'A','B',NULL,'D'),
(1,'A','B',NULL,'D'),
(2,'A','B','D','C');
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    group_concat(my_column separator '|')
> 1    A|B|D|A|B|D
> 2    A|B|D|C
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e98388ab56b2ccaafd4d9f10e1b8f53)